# I have added new page layout to magento admin but not working at front end

Tags: magento

I am trying to add new layout to default theme.
I have added new page layout to magento admin but it not working at front end.
For admin panel I have added code in app\code\core\Mage\Page\etc\config.xml and I am able to select new added layout at backend, but at the frontend its a blank page.

Comment: Can please provide code..

Comment: Some code can make us see the problem. Also, don't edit the core. Here is a tutorial on how to add a new page layout. http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.com/2013/03/add-custom-page-layout.html

Comment: yes, marius is right, donot edit core file, Please follow his links.It was working for me

Comment: @AmitBera code which I added to app\code\core\Mage\Page\etc\config.xml <zero_column translate="label">
     <label>Flat Printing Pages Layout</label>
     <reference name="root">
      <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>page/0column.phtml</template>
        <layout_handle>page_zero_column</layout_handle>
        <is_default>1</is_default>
      </action>      
     </reference>
    </zero_column>